# Creating pointer to read from .las binary file throws bad_alloc error

Tags: c++, pointers, bad-alloc, las

I am currently writing code to read in a .las (LIDAR point data) file. After reading in the file, I created a pointer to iterate through all the points. However, it gives me a bad_alloc error.

The only thing I can think of is that header is not the same size as the las file header specifies it should be. I double checked my header and I don't think I see anything wrong.

All the header variables in Header and PointRecord3 come from this [documentation](https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/asprs_las_format_v12.pdf), pages 3 and 10 respectively.

UPDATE: the number of points reading in is 402,673,112. However, when I open it in other LIDAR software to double check and the number of points is only 5,104,152. I believe the reason for this is because I filtered the cloud in other software before opening it in C++, therefore reducing the number of points.

Here is my code:

```
#ifndef POINTCLOUD_H
#define POINTCLOUD_H
#pragma once
#include <string>


class PointCloud
{
    public:
        PointCloud(const std::string &path);

    private:
        struct __attribute__((packed)) Header {

            char magic[4];
            uint16_t fileourceID;
            uint16_t globalEncoding;
            uint32_t guiData1;
            uint16_t guiData2;
            uint16_t guiData3;
            uint8_t guiData[8];
            uint8_t versionMaj, versionMin;
            char systemIdentifer[32];
            char genSoftware[32];
            uint16_t creationDay, creationYear;
            uint16_t headerSize;
            uint32_t pointDataOffset;
            uint32_t numVarLenRecords;
            uint8_t pointDataRecordFormat;
            uint16_t pointDataRecordLen;
            uint32_t numberOfPoints;
            uint32_t numPointsByReturn[5];
            double scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ;
            double offX, offY, offZ;
            double minX, minY, minZ;
            double maxX, maxY, maxZ;
        };

        struct __attribute__((packed)) PointRecord3 {
            uint32_t X, Y, Z;
            uint16_t intensity;
            uint8_t flags;
            uint8_t classification;
            uint8_t scanAngleRank;
            uint8_t userData;
            uint16_t pointSourceID;
            double gpsTime;
            uint16_t red;
            uint16_t green;
            uint16_t blue;
        }; 



#include "PointCloud.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

PointCloud::PointCloud(const string &path)
{
    read(path);
}

void PointCloud::read(const string &path) {
    ifstream in(path.c_str(), ios::binary );
    if(in.is_open()){
        Header header;
        in.read((char *)&header, sizeof(header));

        assert(header.versionMaj == 1 && header.versionMin == 2);
        cout << "headerSize " << header.headerSize << " == " << sizeof(header) << " size of header struct" <<endl;

        cout << "FILE TYPE: LAS " << (int)header.versionMaj << "." << (int)header.versionMin << endl;
        cout << "POINT DATA OFFSET: " << (int)header.pointDataOffset <<endl;
        cout << "POINT DATA RECORD FORMAT: " << (int)header.pointDataRecordFormat <<endl;
        cout << "NUMBER OF POINTS: " << (int)header.numberOfPoints << endl;



        PointRecord3 *points = new PointRecord3[header.numberOfPoints];

       in.seekg(header.pointDataOffset);
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < header.numberOfPoints; i++) {
            in.read((char *) (points + i), sizeof(*points));
       }
       if(in.good()) {

          throw runtime_error("error");
        }

      delete points;


    } else {
        cout << "file not opened" << endl;

    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Also here is the output of the LAS file header:

```
file signature:             'LASF'
  file source ID:             0
  global_encoding:            0
  project ID GUID data 1-4:   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  version major.minor:        1.2
  system identifier:          'EXPORT'
  generating software:        'RiSCAN_PRO'
  file creation day/year:     317/2018
  header size:                227
  offset to point data:       313
  number var. length records: 1
  point data format:          3
  point data record length:   34
  number of point records:    5104152
  number of points by return: 5104152 0 0 0 0
  scale factor x y z:         0.00025 0.00025 0.00025
  offset x y z:               267805 3197054 13
  min x y z:                  267804.25250 3196596.64500 -1.89000
  max x y z:                  268760.27000 3197586.23000 23.33000
variable length header record 1 of 1:
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34735
  length after header  32
  description          'GeoKeyDirectoryTag (mandatory)'
    GeoKeyDirectoryTag version 1.1.0 number of keys 3
      key 1025 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 2 - GTRasterTypeGeoKey: RasterPixelIsPoint
      key 1024 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 3 - GTModelTypeGeoKey: ModelTypeGeocentric
      key 2048 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 4326 - GeographicTypeGeoKey: GCS_WGS_84
reporting minimum and maximum for all LAS point record entries ...
  X               -2989    3821075
  Y            -1829412    2128911
  Z              -59559      41318
  intensity       32767      32768
  return_number       1          1
  number_of_returns   1          1
  edge_of_flight_line 0          0
  scan_direction_flag 1          1
  classification      0          0
  scan_angle_rank     0          0
  user_data           0          0
  point_source_ID     0          0
  gps_time 0.000000 0.000000
  Color R 0 0
        G 0 0
        B 0 0
number of first returns:        5104152
number of intermediate returns: 0
number of last returns:         5104152
number of single returns:       5104152
overview over number of returns of given pulse: 5104152 0 0 0 0 0 0
histogram of classification of points:
         5104152  never classified (0)
```

Comment: You want `delete[] points;`. How far does your program go before it crashes? Does it output `blah`?

Comment: You say "a .las file" as if everyone knows what that is. We don't.  What is a ".las" file?

Comment: I will bet that if you write out the number of points value that you read, your mystery will be solved.

Comment: Use smart pointers and containers in modern C++. *Not* manual memory management.

Comment: looks like there is some missing source code from the class definition. Modify your output of the header values with some additional members such as `numberOfPoints` and then update your posted question with the output that is generated. At what point is the `bad_alloc` error generated?

Comment: UPDATE: It crashes when I create the pointer *points and I updated my code with the total number of points.

Comment: @p0ps1c1e It's not surprising that trying to create an array of roughly 11GB in size fails. You might want to consider memory mapping the file rather than reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. So what was happening was that C++ was adding a few extra bytes which resulted in my header struct being 5 bytes larger than the actual file header.  I fixed this by adding #pragma pack (push, 1).

```
#ifndef POINTCLOUD_H
#define POINTCLOUD_H
#pragma pack (push, 1)
#include <string>


struct float3
{
    float x, y, z;

};

class PointCloud
{
    public:
        PointCloud(const std::string &path);

    private:

        struct __attribute__((packed)) Header
        {

            char fileSig[4];
            uint16_t fileourceID;
            uint16_t globalEncoding;
            uint32_t guiData1;
            uint16_t guiData2;
            uint16_t guiData3;
            uint8_t guiData[8];
            uint8_t versionMaj, versionMin;
            char systemIdentifer[32];
            char genSoftware[32];
            uint16_t creationDay, creationYear;
            uint16_t headerSize;
            uint32_t pointDataOffset;
            uint32_t numVarLenRecords;
            uint8_t pointDataRecordFormat;
            uint16_t pointDataRecordLen;
            uint32_t numberOfPoints;
            uint32_t numPointsByReturn[5];
            double scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ;
            double offX, offY, offZ;
            double minX, minY, minZ;
            double maxX, maxY, maxZ;
        };

        struct __attribute__((packed)) PointRecord3
        {
            uint32_t X, Y, Z;
            uint16_t intensity;
            uint8_t flags;
            uint8_t classification;
            uint8_t scanAngleRank;
            uint8_t userData;
            uint16_t pointSourceID;
            double gpsTime;
            uint16_t red;
            uint16_t green;
            uint16_t blue;
        };


        void read(const std::string &path);
};



#endif // POINTCLOUD_H
```